# Using Functions in triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, function, triggers

I have created a function,which i think is right but im not sure how to call it in the trigger. I know the trigger is wrong but thats what i have tried
Function:

```
    create or replace function log_in(pass in varchar2, user in varchar2)
return number
is
  match_count number;
begin
  select count(*)
    into match_count
    from Member
    where username=user
    and password=pass;
    return match_count;
end;
```

Trigger:

```
    create or replace TRIGGER PASSWORDCHECK 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Login 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
usern VARCHAR2(12);
pass VARCHAR2(12);
result number;
BEGIN
usern := :new.username;
pass := :new.password;
/*Select LOG_IN(pass,usern)INTO result From MEMBER Where usern = Username;*/
result := LOG_IN(pass,usern);
If result = 1 THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Login Succesful');
ElsIF result = 0 THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Login Failed');
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Sorry its sql oracle im using, i think thats what you are looking for

Comment: Wny are you calling dbms_output in a trigger?  There is nothing to see it normally.

Comment: i had to add in code so just trying to figure out how to use the trigger its was just thrown in there

Comment: At a first glance, your code is correct. What problem do you have with it? Mutation? At a second glance: what problem does this code solve? To control user's data and connections count oracle has another tools, quite simple and useful.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do here. If you change the password of a use, then the login from the trigger is going to fail. What happens then? What problem are you actually trying to solve? You have presented a solution to something, but it would be good to know what it is that this solution is for.

Comment: Ive changed it around a bit but the function should be checking if the password entered matches the username this should be returned as either a 0 or 1 then the trigger checks that if the return value is 1 login successful else if 0 login failed this is my new code but i could be completly wrong any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming all login attempts fail?

USER is a keyword, which identifies the current schema:

```
SQL> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
REF
```

As it's unlikely any of your users have the same name as the schema your count is always returning 0.